# SQL query of certain type and categorization

Tags: mysql, sql

The model i am querying: (a basic version of stackoverflow)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/210dv.png

I am trying to perform the following SQL query:
**For a particular user (e.g. user 3982), the net votes they have received on answers to questions
in each tag.**

I have the following query, but inside of each COUNT i'm not sure how to choose the right tag from tags.tag_description while selecting the same tag outside of the count.

EDITED TO REFLECT THE GROUP BY RECCOMENDATION

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT tag_description, 
    (SELECT COUNT(vote.vote_id) 
    FROM vote 
    JOIN answervote USING (vote_id)
    JOIN answers USING (answer_id)
    JOIN questions USING (question_id)
    JOIN tags USING (question_id)
    WHERE vote.vote_choice = 'u' 
    AND  vote.vote_id = answervote.vote_id 
    AND answervote.answer_id = answer.answer_id
    AND tags.question_id = questions.question_id
    GROUP BY tag.tag_description)

  -(SELECT COUNT(vote_choice) 
    FROM vote 
    JOIN answervote USING (vote_id)
    JOIN answers USING (answer_id)
    JOIN questions USING (question_id)
    JOIN tags USING (question_id)
    WHERE vote.vote_choice = 'd'
    AND  vote.vote_id = answervote.vote_id 
    AND answervote.answer_id = answer.answer_id
    AND tags.question_id = questions.question_id
    GROUP_BY tags.tag_description) AS total_points

FROM tags
JOIN questions USING (question_id)
JOIN user USING (user_id)
WHERE user.user_id = 3982
GROUP BY tags.tag_description;
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the inner selects in this case by using a trick called conditional aggregation:

```
select
    tag_description,
    sum(case
        when vote.vote_choice = 'u' then 1
        when vote.vote_choice = 'd' then -1
    else 0 end) as total_points
from
    vote
        join
    answervote
        using (vote_id)
        join
    answers
        using (answer_id)
        join
    questions
        using (question_id)
        join
    tags
        using (question_id)
where
    questions.user_id = 3982
group by
    tags.tag_description;
```